# Why did Chunargadh forces keep advancing on Vijaygadh even after Shivdutt got Chandrakanta and Chapla kidnapped?

Tags: chandrakanta

Shivdutt (King of Chunargadh) had listened that Chandrakanta was a top-notch beauty and few days ago, he had encountered Chapla who mesmerised him with her beauty before freeing Tej Singh. He sent a proposal to Vijaygadh to get Chandrakanta as wife and Chapla as dowry gift. Vijaygadh's king Jay Singh became mad at this and refused the proposal.

Then, Chunargadh attacked Vijaygadh to get Chandrakanta and Chapla by force. Vijaygadh went in defense mode and Naugadh sent help. At that moment, Chandrakanta and Chapla's beheaded bodies were found at the palace. In reality, Shivdutt had Chandrakanta and Chapla kidnapped and those were fake bodies. This can be considered Shivdutt's victory. And yet, his forces kept advancing towards Vijaygadh. Why is that?

I don't think it was a defense act. He had nothing to fear about. Vijaygadh and Naugadh's combined forces couldn't match Chunargadh's forces in number. And, Chunargadh's forces could always defend the border of its kingdom in case of attack by Vijaygadh.

Comment: Again, you might want to make it clear whether you're addressing these questions to the book or the TV show.

Comment: @Valorum Story is same for both.

Comment: Yowzers. She *is* a top-notch beauty; https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWYwNTcxY2MtMGRhYy00NjhhLTkyOWEtNTk3ODY4NWIwNjZmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDY2NTE2NDM@._V1_UY268_CR87,0,182,268_AL_.jpg

Comment: Haha.. TV show needed to use an inexpensive actress, but the book describes her as most beautiful girl on the planet.

Comment: I watched it as child but it is possible Shivdutt wanted to keep them distracted from finding out the truth.